# How to JEST test a lightning-input of type "file"

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I have an LWC that updloads a file:

```
<lightning-input type="file" label={label.AttachInvoice} accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/gif, application/pdf" onchange={invoiceUploadHandler}></lightning-input>
```

Question:  How do you set up a JEST test for this onchange handler?  Where do you inject a test file?

Adding my handler:

```
    invoiceUploadHandler(event) {

    let theFile = event.target.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let temp = this;

    reader.onload = function() {

        let theContents = this.result.split(/,/)[1]; 

        temp.invoiceUploads = temp.invoiceUploads.slice();
        temp.invoiceUploads.push('Carrier Invoice');

        doUploadFile({ loadId: temp.recordId, filename: 'Carrier Invoice', contentType: theFile.type, contents: theContents })

        .then(result => {             
            LightningUtil.processMessagesAndErrors2(temp, result);   
        })
        .catch(error => {
            LightningUtil.logError(temp, error);
        });    
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(theFile);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to dispatch a change event with the details of the file within it so your handler can run (and be tested). Unsure how complicated your component is, I'd recommend adding an easy way to grab the input you're looking for by setting a data attribute (`data-testid`).

```javascript
<lightning-input 
    type="file" 
    label={label.AttachInvoice} 
    accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/gif, application/pdf" 
    onchange={invoiceUploadHandler} 
    data-testid="file-upload-input">
</lightning-input>
```

Once you grab the input you're after, you set the details of the event (files) and then dispatch the "change" event on the element

```javascript
const fileName = "testFile.docx";
const documentId = "01010101001";

const uploadedFile = [{ name: fileName, documentId: documentId }];

const uploadElement = component.shadowRoot.querySelector('[data-testid="file-upload-input"]');

uploadElement.dispatchEvent(
    new CustomEvent("change", {
        detail: { files: uploadedFile },
    })
);
```

Just a note, `FileReader` will need to be stubbed as you won't be able to have it run in a jest test. There's some questions around that

- [How to mock filereader using jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58644737/how-to-mock-filereader-using-jest)
- [How to test FileReader onload using simulate change in jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61572070/how-to-test-filereader-onload-using-simulate-change-in-jest)

Not to mention you'll want to mock return data for your `doUploadFile` call. Something like below could at confirm the reader method was called.

```javascript
let readerOnLoadMock = jest.spyOn(FileReader.prototype, 'onload').mockImplementation(() => null);

//dispatch change event for file input

//then, assert the onload method was called
expect(readerOnLoadMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Thank you, Kris!

Comment: Thank you @Kris, Can you please suggest how to stub the FileReader in this example. I get following error - TypeError: 'get onload' called on an object that is not a valid instance of FileReader.